# tmux status-line: italicize zoomed window name?

Tags: tmux

I've customized my tmux statusline, and I'd like to add a visual indicator for when the current window is zoomed (`resize-pane -Z`).

I've seen several examples of how to apply a different foreground color,

```
setw -g window-status-current-format " #{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=red],#[fg=black]}#W#[fg=default]"
```

Since I have italics working in tmux, I want to apply them in this case. I tried:

```
setw -g window-status-current-format " #{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=red,italics],#[fg=black]}#W#[fg=default]"
```

but this doesn't work. When zoomed it just shows empty spaces, and when unzoomed it shows `italics],bash` ("bash" being the window_name).

It seems to be treating the `,` in `#[fg=red,italics]` as one of the separators for the overall conditional form,

```
#{?test,alternative1,alternative2}
```

It *does* correctly handle a comma embedded in `alternative2`, e.g.

```
setw -g window-status-current-format " #{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=red],#[fg=black,italics]}#W#[fg=default]"
```

so if I wanted to italicize the *unzoomed* window name, I'd be in luck, but since I don't have a way to turn the conditional around, I am SOL.

Does anyone know a way to get this working, or is this an issue I should bring to the tmux project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working and now I'm not sure I actually *like* it, but it's good to know that it can be done. It's not entirely clear from the documentation, but I noticed in this answer this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1021365/162069) that you can specify the text attribute in a separate `#[]` group instead of using a comma-separated list, so this works:

```
setw -g window-status-current-format " #{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=red]#[italics],#[fg=black]}#W#[fg=default]"
```

Answer (score 1):

probably a bit outdated answer yet helpful for anyone out there that might need help!

I have managed to do that with the following code :)

I will post the whole status bar in case anyone finds it any helpfull

```
set -g status-left '#[fg=black,bg=green] #S#{prefix_highlight}#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=green,bg=green]#{?mouse,#[fg=black] MOUSE#[bg=green]#[fg=green],#[bg=red]#[fg=green]#[fg=white]#[bg=red]MOUSE#[bg=green]#[fg=red]}#{?pane_synchronized,#[fg=black] SYNC#[bg=green]#[fg=green],#[bg=red]#[fg=green]#[fg=white]#[bg=red]SYNC#[bg=green]#[fg=red]}#{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=black] #[bg=green]#[fg=green],#[bg=red]#[fg=green]#[fg=white]#[bg=red]#[bg=green]#[fg=red]}#[fg=green,bg=black] #W #[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=green,bg=black] #(whoami) CPU: #{cpu_percentage}Online:#{online_status}#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]'
set -g status-right '#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=green,bg=black]#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=white,bg=black]Bat: #{battery_percentage}#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=black,bg=green]#(rainbarf --battery --remaining )'

setw -g window-status-format '#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[default] #I  #W #[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]'
setw -g window-status-current-format '#[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=green,bg=black] #I  #W  #F #[fg=green,bg=black,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]'
```